# Seeing wrong behavior while toggling visiblility in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a fresh new webform project with the following code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1._default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"><title></title></head>
<body><form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="divrpt">
        <%--problematic div--%> <div runat="server" id="testdiv">test</div> <%--problematic div--%>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="testrpt">
            <HeaderTemplate>abc</HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnHide" Text="Hide test" OnClick="btnHide_Click"/>
    </div>
    <div runat="server" id="divbtn" visible="false">
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShow" Text="Show abc without test" OnClick="btnShow_Click"/>
    </div>
</form></body></html>
```

and this

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private void Bind()
        {
            var test = (new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }).AsEnumerable();

            testrpt.Visible = test.Any();
            testdiv.Visible = !testrpt.Visible;

            testrpt.DataSource = test;
            testrpt.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnHide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            divrpt.Visible = false;
            divbtn.Visible = true;
            btnHide.Text = "hide abc";
        }

        protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bind(); //this will still make testdiv being visible WRONG BEHAVIOR expected
            divrpt.Visible = true;
            divbtn.Visible = false;
            // Bind(); //this wont make testdiv being visible PROPER BEHAVIOR
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at `btnShow_Click` you can see that I have a `Bind()` before and after some visibility toggling

If you comment out the first one and uncomment the second one, you will get the expected behavior that I expect by calling the first `Bind()`

My question is simply, why does the first `Bind()` doesn't work as I expect?

Expected behavior;

1. run (page show text `test` with a button saying `hide test`)
2. click on `hide test` (page refresh with a single button saying `Show abc without test`)
3. click on `Show abc without test` (page refresh and show text `abc` and a button saying `hide abc`)

Current behavior;

1. run (page show text `test` with a button saying `hide test`)
2. click on `hide test` (page refresh with a single button saying `Show abc without test`)
3. click on `Show abc without test` (page refresh and show text `test abc` and a button saying `hide abc`)

I'm using, while debugging this, new empty webform project using .Net Framework 4.5, Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2 and the IIS Express that come with Visual Studio

Comment: are the Visible properties not set correctly or do you mean the Output is not correct ?

Comment: maybe there are some Timing issues with the postback

Comment: @S.L. exactly, first screen will be a button with hide test, when you click on it you should see a new button with show a b c without the test text, but test text still show

Comment: @PaulZahra i think that too .... i see no reason why the result of `Bind()`will change

Comment: @PaulZahra yes it should always get the same result but if you test the code, run it without changing the code then comment out the first Bind() and uncomment the second Bind() you will see a different result

Comment: @Fredou try to call `Bind()`just once in Page Load Event to bind the datasource.

Comment: @S.L. this is a small reproducible code sample, the real code does have a bind in the page load and the collection does change over time and it does have case where it is empty

Comment: @PaulZahra the issue is not about divrpt or the repeater, the issue is about testdiv

Comment: @Fredou i am sorry i cannot test it right now :(

Comment: Just a thought, you can use a asp:Panel, this renders as a div and then you won't need to set runas on a divided